# Please help me with usb stick

Tags: usb

OK maybe i did something stupid but i hope its not hopeless.

I tried to compress one file on my usb stick and it didnt have enough space and now when i put my usb in pc it says free 1,6 gb  free 2.4 gb but when i open removable disk it says there are no files on this disk.

I tried open it on other pc and it says same thing.

How can I find my files and folders on it

Comment: Try [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva).

Comment: I don't think it says " free 1,6 gb free 2.4 gb"

Answer (score 2):

First you need to not to freak out, because it is either so simple to recover your files, or they are gone forever.

These are the options available:

1. The best would be to take your usb stick to the nearest data recovery center, and tell them the whole story and ask them to recover your files. They are the best people who could do that for you. (There is this center in our town which says they could recover your data on your hard disk even if it has been totally ruined in a bucket of water or fire, I never tried this claim of theirs but they recovered my old hard drive like it was a new one). You should only try this, if your information on that USB stick is highly sensitive and very very important to you (because they might charge you real good, and I think it's worth it, considering what they do.)
2. You could try a data recovery application. You could try [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) or your own favorite data recovery application. Or maybe one that is specifically designed for usb sticks.
3. Which might be a little bit more complicated: would be to try opening your USB stick using a HEX editor and trying to look for your files. I highly recommend [WinHEX](http://www.x-ways.net/winhex/%E2%80%8E) because not only you could engineer your files out all by yourself by reading the hex values, but you could also try letting WinHEX itself recover all your lost files for you.

Comment: I forgot to tell you this: Once you have WinHex installed, run it, then, while you have your USB flash memory plugged-in to one of your USB ports, in WinHex go to : Menu bar>>Tool>>Open Disk... (F9) and in the 'Edit Disk' window choose your USB stick drive and click OK. There you should be seeing all your files. If not, go to Menu bar>>Tools>>Disk Tools>>File Recovery by Type... and if any messages appear read them and respond appropriately, then in the 'File Header Search on Drive blah' and change other settings appropriately and then click OK, and wait for it to recover your data.